# Why don't we transpose $\delta^{l+1}$ in back propagation?

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

Using this neural network as an example:

[image: NN Example]

The weight matrices are then

$$ W_0=[2\times4], W_1=[4\times4], W_2=[4\times2]$$

To find the error for the last layer, we use
$$ \delta^{[2]} = \nabla C \odot \sigma'(z^{[2]})$$
which makes sense. This will produce a $[1\times 2]$ vector. But to find the error in the next layer, we use
$$ \delta^{[1]} = (W_2^T\delta^{[2]})\odot \sigma'(z^{[1]}) $$

This appears to try to multiply a $[4\times2]$ matrix and a $[1\times 2]$ matrix together, which is illegal. Am I just wrong about how the layers are represented? Should $z^{[n]}$ really be a $[l\times 1]$ vector? That doesn't really make sense to me, because it would be multiplied by an $[l\times m]$ matrix as the feed-forward continues. Do we just always represent $\delta^{[n]}$ as a $[l\times 1]$ vector, and the formula doesn't mention this as it's common knowledge?

What am I missing here?

([Note: these formulae are based on this book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some wrong dimension here. Rules  for Dim of weight $W^{[l]} = d^{l} * d^{l-1} $

$ W_0 = [ 4 * 2 ] $

$ W_2 = [ 2 * 4 ] $

As

$  dim (z^{[2]})  = [2 * 1] $

so is

$ \delta^{[2]}$

So

$ W_{2}^{T} \delta^{2} $ is $ [4 * 2 ] * [2 * 1] = [4 * 1 ]  dimension $

Comment: Really? Then how does it feed-forward the data? The input is $[1\times 2]$ or $[2 \times 1]$ if I'm wrong about layers being row-vectors. In either case, you can't multiply the input by the first weight matrix

Comment: $ z = Wx $  $ [ 4* 2] [ 2* 1]  = [4 * 1]  $ which is the input dim for the next layer.

Comment: Oh, you know what. I had the whole thing backwards. I was thinking $z=xW+b$ when it's really $z=Wx + b$. This makes sense.

Comment: Yes. I hope you've got it.